# Post JSON ajax request with cors not working in IE10/Edge

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, ajax, wcf, cross-domain

**Background:-** I created a WCF service hosted in my local system IIS. Service exposes GET/POST method and cross domain enabled and can be accessed using https too. To make it accessible, self signed certificate is used.

**Testing:-** When i try to do cross domain ajax call it work fine for GET request and POST request (only those post method which are not accepting data as a json) in IE10/Edge. I'm able to make cross domain call for any GET/POST request in chrome/Firebox browser. Only it's IE 10/Edge which cause problem to make cross domain call for POST request when contenttype:accept/json parameter is passed in ajax call.

**Research:-** I read lots of blogs/mdn and get to know specification of cors in which IE does not follow cors religiously. I know cors specification does not alloe custom header/header's value due to which cors preflight aborted.

*Example of ajax request i'm making:-*

```
var postDT = { "postValue": "test" };
        debugger;
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(postDT),
            url: "http://ateet3371/Service1.svc/postdata",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var a = jqXHR;
                alert(jqXHR + '---' + textStatus + '---' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

If i removed `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` then it throw bad request error else it throw access denied error.

And method implementation in WCF is:-

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "PostResponseData")]
    string PostResponseData(PostDataTest postDT);
```

And datacontract is:-

```
[DataContract]
public class PostDataTest
{
    private string post_value;

    // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
    [DataMember]
    public string postValue
    {

        get { return post_value; }
        set { post_value = value; }
    }
}
```

If i use method PostUrl data then ajax call is executed successfully and return proper results if ContentType:"Application/json" header is removed from request.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "PostUrlData/{value}")]
    string PostUrlData(string value);
```

*I already write code in BeginRequest event in Global.asax of WCF to handle Options request:-*

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS" )
        { 
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Session");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DAV, content-length, Allow" );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000" );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

And i can't enable `Allow cross domain call` setting in IE as end user would not do such steps.

**Stuck in Problem:-** But still not able to do JSON data post call in IE 10/Edge (which are cors enabled).

***(Edited) Updates:***
IIS site where WCF is hosted have only **Anonymous Authentication** enabled while other authentication are disabled.
***Even I tried with valid certificate for https but still it is not working for IE but work perfect for chrome.***

Please help me as I go through lots of article and blog and still not able to resolve the issue.
Your help will be greatly appreciated!

***EXPERT's PLEASE HELP ME!***